# openrefine, cluster and edit two datasets

Tags: openrefine

i have two datasets. Column A has ids from dataset one, column B, has the data i need to cluster and edit, using the various available algorithms. Dataset 2, has again in the first column, the ids, and in the next column, the data. I need to reconcile, data only from dataset one, against data from the second dataset. What i have done so far, is use one dataset, merge the two, but then openrefine, gives me mixed results, ie messy data that exist only in dataset two, which is not what i want, in the current phase.

I have also investigated Reconcile-csv, but without success, in achieving desired result. Any ideas?

Comment: What was the problem with reconcile-csv ?

Comment: i do not want to merge datasets, i just want a report, that would say: The following ids from dataset one, are almost the same with the following ids from dataset two, what i would like, is the closest to what cluster and edit returns. A list of similar values, but between two different datasets. if Reconcile-csv has a way to accomplish this, please let me know how this could be done.

Comment: Certainly. Once your dataset 1 is reconciled with dataset 2 using reconcile-csv, you can add a new column based on the reconciled column using either of the following GREL formulas: `cell.recon.match.id` or `cell.recon.match.name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reconcile-CSV is a very good tool, but not very user friendly. You can use as an alternative the free Excel plugin [Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011). It's very easy to use, as evidenced by this screencast. One constraint: the two tables to be reconciled must be in Excel table format (select and CTRL + L).

[image]

And here is the same procedure with reconcile-csv (the GREL formula used is `cell.recon.best.name` and comes from [here](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Variables))

[image]

Comment: this is a very useful tip also

Comment: I've added another screencast with reconcile-csv

Comment: seems i cannot find where change the matching score, in openrefine. Now i get only complete matches

Comment: Not sure to understand your problem. The best score can be obtained with `cell.recon.best.score` and the list of all scores with  `cell.recon.candidates.score`

Comment: in the judgement facet, i get say 100 as matched. Which is score 1. How could i lower the matched level to say 0.85?

Comment: You can do that using "Reconcile -> Facets ->  Best candidates scores", playing with the facet, then "Reconcile -> Action --> match each cell to its best candidate", but it is a bit difficult to explain visually in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to using the reconciliation approach described by Ettore is to use algorithms similar to the 'key collision' clustering algorithms to create shared keys between the two data sets and then use this to do lookups between the data sets using the 'cross' function.

As an example for Column B in each data set you could 'Add column based on this column' using the GREL:

```
value.fingerprint()
```

This creates the same key as is used by the "Fingerprint" clustering method. Lets call the new column 'Column C'

You can then look up between the two projects using the following GREL in Dataset 2:

```
cells["Column C"].cross("Dataset 1","Column C")
```

If the values in both Dataset 1 and Dataset 2 would have clustered based on the fingerprint cluster then the lookup between the projects will work

You can also use the phonetic keying algorithms to create match keys in Column C if that works better. What you can't do using this method (as far as I know) is the equivalent of the Nearest Neighbour matching - you'd have to have a reconciliation service with fuzzy matching of some kind, or merge the two data sets, to achieve this.

Owen

Comment: this is also so useful tip, going to also use it, like you said, as an alternative. Issue i face with this, is i do not know how to load the two datasets in opernerfine.As two different projects, is the only way i know of

Comment: @Beti It's the only way. A sheet = a table = an Open Refine project.